# Selenium web-driver can not get option text

Tags: selenium, webdriver, html-select

I can not get text value from options

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();

Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select")));
        List <WebElement> elementCount = oSelect.getOptions();
        int iSize = elementCount.size();
        System.out.println("size : " + iSize);

        for(int i = 0; i< iSize ; i++){
            WebElement webElement = elementCount.get(i);
            String text = webElement.getText();
            System.out.println("text: " + text);
            String location = webElement.getLocation().toString();
            System.out.println("location: " + location);
            String tagName = webElement.getTagName();
            System.out.println("tagName: " + tagName);
            String id = ((RemoteWebElement) webElement).getId();
            System.out.println("id: " + id);
            boolean displayed = webElement.isDisplayed();
            System.out.println("displayed: " + displayed);
            boolean enabled = webElement.isEnabled();
            System.out.println("enabled :"  + enabled);
            boolean selected = webElement.isSelected();
            System.out.println("selected :"  + selected);
            String value = webElement.getAttribute("value");
            System.out.println("value: " + value);
            webElement.click();
        }
```

and HTML source

```
<select name="subscriberSelect" id="subscriber-select"
<option value="5299" selected="selected">5 299</option>
<option value="3609">3 609</option>
<option value="2415">2 415</option>
.....
</select>
```

Result is:

```
size : 11
text: 
location: (0, 0)
tagName: option
id: 0.3487315878737718-2
displayed: false
enabled :true
selected :true
text: 
location: (0, 0)
tagName: option
id: 0.3487315878737718-3
displayed: false
enabled :true
selected :false
....
```

and finally when I wan to select another option

```
oSelect.selectByIndex(i);
```

I am receiving en exception

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Basicially I am facing 2 issues
1, text in option tags is not printed - I am receiving empty string
2, `oSelect.selectByIndex(1);` throws en exception

UPDATE 1:
1, issue is solved - helps

```
webElement.getAttribute("value");
```

2, second problem

```
webElement.click();
```

throws an exception

```
enabled :true
selected :true
value: 13609
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

UPDATE 2: in both cases drop down is not open - I am watching on it when web driver is running

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select")));
oSelect.selectByValue(phoneNumber);         
driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select")).sendKeys(phoneNumber); // org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

if I change code like this:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select"))).build().perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("subscriber-select"))).click(); //org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: subscriber-select
```

Comment: The problem is that `String text = webElement.getText();` doesn't print anything or that you can't select new option?

Comment: yes no string is printed. I will be expecting text in value option but I am receiving empty string, even when I add Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);

Comment: I added solution for the text to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try three things:

- Use Select

  ```
  // by value instead of by index
  Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select")));
  oSelect.selectByValue(value);
  ```
- Send keys

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select")).sendKeys(value);
  ```
- Click on the option:

  ```
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select"))).build().perform();
  // or 
  driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select")).click();
  // the purpose is to open the drop down

  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[value='" + value + "']"))).click();
  ```

For the text you can use `String text = webElement.getAttribute("value");`

Comment: I add wait 20 sec but result is the same exception

Comment: I used your solution and I received org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: subscriber-select

Comment: super 1, point getting value from combobox is solved, your solution [webElement.getAttribute("value")] helps. thx for it. Unfortunately second issue still remainds.

Comment: @user802293  Is the combo box completely visible on the page? or do you need to scroll to see it?

Comment: only first item is visible....I do not know why I am getting exception for your code suggestion....   WebElement comboBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("subscriber-select"))); // ElementNotVisibleException....this code is valid    WebElement numbersDrop = driver.findElement(By.id("subscriber-select"));
   List<WebElement> numbers = numbersDrop.findElements(By.tagName("option")); but exception occurs here :    dropdown.selectByIndex(i); // ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: @user802293 I edited my answer and added few options you can try.

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<IWebElement> DDL = driver.FindElement(By.Id("subscriber-select")).FindElements(By.TagName("option"));

for (int i = 0; i < DDL.Count; i++)
{
    string selectText = ddl[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: I used your solution but unfortunately I am receiving empty string